# Alamofire parameter encoding, dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, parameters, alamofire

Want to send this to Alamofire using Swift...

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download    
 --header "Authorization: Bearer ab-xxx-x-x"     
 --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.001.png\"}"
```

But can't figure how to get the second --header you see here into the code? Tried several times with different combinations, but ...

```
JSON: 114 bytes Optional("Error in call to API function \"files/download\": Must provide HTTP header \"Dropbox-API-Arg\" or URL parameter \"arg\".")
```

I provided it, but not correctly evidently?

```
let subPart: NSDictionary = ["path": sourcePath]
let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token2Save, "Dropbox-API-Arg": String(describing: subPart)]

    Alamofire.request("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.init(options: []), headers: headers).responseData(completionHandler: {feedback in
```

Comment: `print(String(describing: subPart))`, whats the output?

Comment: try `.JSON` instead of `JSONEncoding.init(options: [])`

Comment: Output is " {
    path = "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.001.png";
} for the subPart seen here.  .JSON does compile as an Alamofire option. Note I am using Swift 3.0 and Alamofire 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ureka!! THANK YOU Mr UB for giving me those tips. Found the solution.

```
let subPart: Dictionary =  ["path":sourcePath]
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: subPart, options: [])
        let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token2Save, "Dropbox-API-Arg": dataString!]
    } catch {
        print("crunch")
    }

 Alamofire.request("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.init(options: []), headers: headers).responseData(completionHandler: {feedback in
        guard feedback.result.value != nil else {
        print("Error: did not receive data", print("request \(request) feedback \(feedback)"))
        return
        }
        guard feedback.result.error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on list_folder")
            print(feedback.result.error)
            return
        }
        if let JSON = feedback.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            let dataString = String(data: JSON, encoding: .utf8)
            print("JSON: \(JSON) \(dataString)")
        }
        if let IMAGE = feedback.result.value {
            sharedDataAccess.fnData(index2seek: 0, fnData:  feedback.result.value! as Data)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("previewPane"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        }
    })
```